# Watchify w/ gulp and babel gets progressively slower

Tags: gulp, browserify, babeljs, watchify

Everytime watchify detects a change, the bundle time gets slower. There must be something wrong in my gulp task. Anyone any ideas?

```
gulp.task('bundle', function() {
    var bundle = browserify({
            debug: true,
            extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
            entries: path.resolve(paths.root, files.entry)
        });

    executeBundle(bundle);
});

gulp.task('bundle-watch', function() {
    var bundle = browserify({
        debug: true,
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
        entries: path.resolve(paths.root, files.entry)
    });

    bundle = watchify(bundle);
    bundle.on('update', function(){
        executeBundle(bundle);
    });
    executeBundle(bundle);

});

function executeBundle(bundle) {
    var start = Date.now();
    bundle
        .transform(babelify.configure({
            ignore: /(bower_components)|(node_modules)/
        }))
        .bundle()
        .on("error", function (err) { console.log("Error : " + err.message); })
        .pipe(source(files.bundle))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.root))
        .pipe($.notify(function() {
            console.log('bundle finished in ' + (Date.now() - start) + 'ms');
        }))
}
```

Comment: I think I already fixed it, adding these two options to the bundle seem to fix it: cache: {},
        packageCache: {}

Comment: Those options are required to use watchify.

Comment: I have those options configured, but am still seeing a similar issue. With each run, the time to rebuild increases, even if the file is just touched (no actual changes) until eventually it crashes with a `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: @Emily post your question as a question.

Answer (score 39):

I had this same problem and investigated it by setting environment variable DEBUG to babel. e.g.:

```
$ DEBUG=babel gulp
```

After inspecting the debug output I noticed that the babelify ran transformations multiple times.

The culprit was that I actually added the transformation every time the bundle was executed. You seem to have the same problem.

Move the

```js
.transform(babelify.configure({
    ignore: /(bower_components)|(node_modules)/
}))
```

from inside `executeBundle` into the tasks. The new `bundle-watch` could be written like this:

```js
gulp.task('bundle-watch', function() {
    var bundle = browserify({
        debug: true,
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
        entries: path.resolve(paths.root, files.entry)
    });

    bundle = watchify(bundle);
    bundle.transform(babelify.configure({
        ignore: /(bower_components)|(node_modules)/
    }))
    bundle.on('update', function(){
        executeBundle(bundle);
    });
    executeBundle(bundle);
});
```

Comment: Wish I could upvote this more. It would have taken me a long time to figure that out.

Comment: Well spotted! Moving the transform out of the method that's called each watchify update fixed a similar issue I had with the build process taking progressively longer and longer over time.